# Question about coil emf

Tags: coil, emf

Hi I am a Korean student studying physics. Recently I was solving a physics problem about coil emf and I have a question.

[image: Circuit]
[image: emf graph of the coil]

As you see in this circuit and the graph, when you close the switch the emf of the coil reaches '-E'(voltage of the battery).
However when you open the switch the emf reaches far more than 'E'
Why does this happen? I already asked my physics teacher and he said that in theory when you open the switch the emf should be 'E'

How does the voltage reach far more than E?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309616/about-misunderstanding-of-lenz-law/309618#309618

Comment: Do not ever excuse yourself for speaking another language that is not your native tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, the inductor follows V = L* di/dt. If the switch is opened instantaneously, then di/dt is infinite, so V is also infinite. In reality, there are small stray capacitances which will cause the Voltage spike to be less than infinite, both in amplitude and in rise time. Also, as noted elsewhere, an arc will likely form across the switch. This will also affect voltage spike.

I have no idea why your professor thought the emf should be equal to V when the switch is open. Theoretically, when the switch is open, the battery current is zero, and the battery does not really enter into the analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand now why the emf is larger than E for this circuit when the circuit is open. However I noticed that the when I asked my teacher about this, the circuit was not actually picture above! It's a little bit different. Could you take a look at this picture and tell me if what my teacher said is true for this circuit?http://i.imgur.com/Ou1SvFB.png

Comment: @NohJeong-Yeon what is the symbol at the top?

Comment: @HarrySvensson It says it's a neon lamp

Comment: @NohJeong-Yeon [Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+5.934295036739208+43+5+50%0Av+800+400+704+400+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0As+800+400+896+400+0+1+false%0Aw+896+400+896+336+2%0Al+800+336+896+336+0+0.1+0.0024221774044778563%0Ar+704+336+800+336+0+10%0Aw+624+336+624+400+0%0Aw+624+336+624+256+0%0A181+704+256+896+256+0+320.76082979898115+100+120+0.4+0.4%0Aw+896+256+896+336+0%0Aw+624+400+704+400+1%0Aw+704+336+624+336+1%0Aw+624+256+704+256+1%0Ag+800+400+800+432+0%0Aw+800+336+800+304+0%0Aw+800+304+784+304+2%0Ao+2+16+0+4099+20+1.6+0+2+2+3%0A) You'll still get something above E.

Comment: After the switch is turned on for a long time, the inductor current will be V/R. At the instant the switch is turned off, the battery current will be zero, and the lamp, resistor and inductor current will all be V/R, but the current will decay toward zero. The voltage at the instant the switch is opened will be determined by the properties of the lamp and resistor value.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, whether it is above E or not depends on the specific component values and the nature of the neon lamp. Basically, if the DC steady state current in the lamp is less than the DC steady-state current in the inductor, the kickback will be greater than E. Hope you can see why.

Comment: I can only see cases where it always goes above E, I can't see any case where it wouldn't.

Comment: @HarrySvensson
It depends on where we are measuring the voltage. I was assuming from A to B (across the neon lamp). My basic point is that the current at the instant the switch is opened is well defined. It is just V/R. When the switch is opened, at that exact instant, the current through the neon lamp instantly change from whatever it was previously to exactly  V/R. So, if V/R is less than the current in the lamp, then the lamp voltage will decrease when the switch is opened. Of course, there will be a polarity inversion. I am only talking about voltage magnitude.

Comment: Ah! Now I'm with you 100% I thought you talked about the link I made.

Answer (score 0):

The inductor stores energy and the energy stored is used by the inductor to try and keep the current flow through it constant. So the instant the switch opens, there is a current flow that the inductor tries to maintain but, the only circuit path includes the fractionally open contacts. Therefore, to maintain current flow it will generate a voltage that can form a small arc. This can be as high as several hundreds or thousands of volts.

Answer (score 0):

When the switch is opened, *all* the energy gets transferred into the parasitic capacitance across the switch contacts. Given Energy = 0. 5 * C * V * V, a very small cap requires the V to increase as squareroot.