# Voltage in an inductor - DC circuit

Tags: voltage, dc, inductor, multisim

I have done a simulation of a simple circuit using Multisim software to simulate the behaviour of the coil in DC circuit. The behaviour of the coil in DC circuit is shown by the below picture:

[image]

[image]

However using the Multisim software, when I open the switch S1 I obtain a negative voltage through the inductor not positive voltage as indicated in the first picture above:

[image]

Same things, when I close the switch,  I obtain a positive voltage (inductor charging) not a negative voltage:

[image]

Is there any explanation for this issue?

Comment: Your first image doesn't show what direction of current and what direction of voltage are considered positive, and what directions are considered negative.

Comment: @ThePhoton: It's OK now. I have added the direction of the current.

Comment: It's still not showing the direction of the voltage

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/how-can-there-be-a-current-without-a-voltage/470182#470182

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-15/magnetic-fields-and-inductance/

Comment: Notice that when the inductor current increases the back emf voltage is induced across the coil (https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/magnetic-load-inductance.png). And this voltage polarity (across the inductor) in opposition to the voltage source drop. Do you see it?

Comment: Look here to see how a "positive" induced voltages resists changes in current.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309616/about-misunderstanding-of-lenz-law/309618#309618 In the circuit below V2, V4, V6 voltage source represent the "induced" voltage.

Comment: @G36: Thanks for your support. So it's OK that the inductor will resist to the increase/decrease of current by producing a voltage between its leads in opposing polarity to the change. However, at t=0s the switch is open so there is no current flowing (0 Amps) and when I close the switch at t=t1 the current will increase so the inductor should resit to this increase of current , but I get a positive voltage same if I replace the inductor by a resistor(I consider just the positive sign of the voltage) . Is there any explanation for this ? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Increases the inductor value (100mH) to be able to see it better what is going on.

Comment: Alo notice that without the inductor the voltage will simply jump form 0V to voltage divider output voltage and it will stay there (no future change in output voltage).

Comment: @G36: But it is a positive voltage sign. It's not opposing the voltage source. Same sign (positive) if it was a resistor.

Comment: But how would a negative voltage at this point opposite anything?

Comment: Also to simplify the thing simply remove the R2 resistor. Leave just R1 resistor in series with the inductor.

Comment: See this it should help you understand why positive voltage opposes the change in the current, in this case. https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Inductance/14.03%3A_Self-Inductance_and_Inductors  (fig 14.3.4) indicates that the induced emf across an inductor always has a polarity that opposes the change in the current. For example, if the current flowing from A to B in Figure 14.3.4a were increasing,

Comment: the induced emf (represented by the imaginary battery) would have the polarity shown in order to oppose the increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to show:

[image]

The inductance is here 10mH and the input voltage V1 is 10V for easy calculations.

The timed switch SW1 starts to conduct at t=10ms and stops at t=50ms. The inductor has zero resistance, so its current grows to 1A.

At t=50ms the inductor current bulldozes its way through R2 because it's the only available route. The inductor voltage jumps to 10V, it jumps as high as needed for continuing the current.  The polarity of the node 3 voltage goes negative because the inductor pulls current through R2 upwards (=from GND towards node 3).

From t=10ms to t=50ms inductor current is fed by voltage divider which as unloaded outputs 5V. Inductor current pulls V(3) onto it knees, the inductor current grows and voltage V(3) decays with time constant L/R. Resistance R=5 ohms (=Thevenin equivalent resistance of the voltage divider).

When the switch opens at t=50ms the inductor current and V(3) decay again with time constant L/R, but this time R=10 ohms, the decay happens with double speed.

I guess your problem is the attempt to approach the practical behaviour of an inductor via a circuit theoretical equation Emf=-L(di/dt). The minus is inserted to make the unmeasurable imagined quantity "electromotive force" to be compliant with the measurable quantities such as voltages between circuit nodes. Check this old discussion of inductor's practical operation: [How does the inductor ''really'' induce voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282053/how-does-the-inductor-really-induce-voltage)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I understand the point that the inductor will resist to the increase/decrease of current by producing a voltage between its leads in opposing polarity to the change (at t=50ms negative sign voltage through the inductor). However, at t=0s the switch is open so there is no current flowing (0 Amps) and when we close the switch at t=10ms the current will increase so the inductor should resit to this increase of current , but we get a positive voltage same if I replace the inductor by a resistor( positive sign of the voltage) . Is there any explanation ?

Comment: You should take that inductor has a working law (otherwise it's not an inductor). The law says that the voltage over an inductor is in any case = L(di/dt) where di/dt is the growth rate (amperes per second) of the inductor current. In any circuit at any time the  voltage over the inductor and the current through the inductor  take values which satisfy this law and all other circuit laws. For this reason often exact solutions can be got by solving differential equations. But simple cases can be solved directly, say  Constant DC voltage U over inductor causes linearly growing current, di/dt=U/L.

Comment: Voltage over an inductor is equal to **minus** L(di/dt)

Comment: @geek not true, see my simulation; voltage of node 3 is at t=10ms  plus 5V and the inductor current grows. The internal emf in inductor at the same time is minus 5V . Emf is unnecessary extra thing which actually explains nothing of the physics,

Comment: So I have to consider the voltage over inductor in a circuit by applying this formula VL= Ldi/dt ?

Comment: (continued) In my circuit at t=10ms the inductor is connected to a non-ideal voltage source which is equivalent with ideal 5V in series with 5 Ohm resistor.  The current starts to grow with rate 5 volts /L but the rate decays because the voltage drops due the series resistance. The current starts from zero, so in the beginning of the conduction period of SW1 there's full 5V at node 3.

Comment: (continued) V=Ldi/dt is ok if V is the voltage over an inductor, voltmeter + at the top end of the inductor and the positive direction of current i is from the top terminal to the bottom terminal through the inductor.

Comment: So when I have to consider the formula VL= - Ldi/dt ? (minus sign when to consider it in the formula?

Comment: When you answer to a person who asks "what's the formula of (the imagined unmeasurable) induced electromotive force or blindly fill numbers to a Kirchoff voltage law formula which is built with electromotive forces instead of purely measurable voltages. BTW picture 1 in the question is wrong like many things in the web. VL isn't right as inductor voltage nor induced EMF. Someone has edited the proper EMF version to crap. The original is here: https://www.dnatechindia.com/Inductor-Introduction.html

Answer (score 7):

When the switch goes open-circuit, the inductor tries to keep the same current flowing AND in the same direction. The only way it can achieve this is by making its upper terminal go negative. So, at the instant in time that the switch opens, the current is forced through the 10 kohm resistor by a large negative voltage at its upper terminal.

Your upper multisim experiment is incorrect because you are using the formula for back emf (i.e. it has a negative sign) and you have no resistance in your circuit to develop the voltage across when the inductor has charged to its peak current.

In other words, the two "experiments" in your question are not the same. Just think about what your upper multisim "experiment" is telling you; when the switch is closed, how can the inductor voltage be anything else other than the applied supply voltage? Your analysis is faulty.

Comment: Andy aka: Thanks for your answer. But I do not understand why formula : VL= -Ldi/dt is incorrect. Can you explain to me more ? Thanks.

Comment: When you are applying a voltage to an inductor and looking at the rate of change of current, the negative sign is inappropriate i.e. it is positive. When you are considering the back emf inside the inductor, you use a negative sign. Just think about it a minute: If you apply 1 volt across an inductor, you would expect current to rise positively and not rise negatively.

Comment: Andy aka: So which circuit I have to use to simulate the beahviour of the inductor in DC circuit ? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your lower circuit is correct in that when you open the switch the inductor's top terminal produces a negative voltage. Your upper circuit is faulty.

Comment: Andy aka : Same thing when I close the switch S1 (I have add a resistor to simulate the charging phase for the inductor). The voltage through the inductor is positive not negative (VL= -Ldi/dt)

Comment: @geek225 I am unsure what you are trying to ask me. Voltage is not "through", voltage is across and current is through. I have no idea which diagram S1 is referring to. Please be clear about this and don't add stuff to your question after I've already answered it without a solid explanation why you feel it is necessary to add stuff.

Comment: I am asking how to simulate the behaviour of the inductor in DC circuit regarding the formula VL= - Ldi/dt . The minus sign in the formula keep me confusing. I do not find a simple circuit to verify the formula and the behaviour of the inductor in DC circuit ( Charging when colsing the switch and discharging when opening the switch)

Comment: You haven't explained why you have added a third simulation. I'm not getting involved in evolving questions. I've told you that your 2nd circuit is correct and I've given you the reason why the voltage is negative. I've also told you that your first circuit is wrong.

Comment: I have added a third simulation to explain that also when I close switch I do not obtain a negative voltage through the inductor (VL= - Ldi/dt). I m really confusing about the minus sign in the formula of the voltage of the inductor.

Comment: You don't need to add that to indicate that you are confused. I got that without the 3rd scenario and, adding that 3rd scenario drove me away from the question because it meant I would have to pick through it bit by bit to see what else you might have changed and what relevance the third stuff has to the overall question. It isn't needed.

Comment: I m sorry for this. Otherwise, how to simulate the charging of the inductor in DC circuit ( a current increase through an inductor ) . I mean, that the inductor resists to the change by producing a voltage between its leads in opposing polarity to the change (So negative voltage)

Comment: Your 2nd scenario does this and if you drop the negative sign, the negative voltage is explained by the rate of change of current being negative. This is why it's important not get get mixed up between formulas and application circuit.

Comment: It's OK for the 2nd scenario I get that the inductor resists to the change(decrease of current). However, for the 3rd scenario (Charging inductor when I close the switch), the inductor does not resist to the increase of current. So how can we explain this ?

Comment: Of course it does - why do you think there is a positive voltage spike. That spike peak matches exactly the applied voltage at the instant it was applied. Let me remind you that this is a question and answer site and not a forum or talking shop.

Comment: But this spike peak is not opposite to the voltage applied. It is in the same way. The inductor does not resist so. My question is so why this voltage is positive and not negative ? Because If I replace the inductor by a resistor I will get also a positive voltage(considering just positive sign). I m sorry for the this extended discussion.

Comment: It is the applied voltage at that instant - how could it be anything else. An inductor does not resist voltage, it resists current change. And it resists the change from 0 mA to the inevitable positive value of current given the fullness of time.

Comment: It's OK. But at t=0s the switch is open so there is no current flowing (0 Amps) and when I close the switch at t=t1 the current will increase so the inductor should resit to this increase of current. So how can we explain this ?

Comment: It resists by it appearing to be an open circuit hence, at t=t1 the supply voltage appears across the inductor and, over the fullness of time, that voltage decays to 0 volts as the inductor charges up. This is actually a repeat of my previous comment. I'm repeating myself myself myself.... You are not listening listening. You are fixated on the minus sign sign sign... LOL

Comment: So If I understand you , I do not to consider emf formula to understand the behaviour of the inductor in DC circuit ?

Comment: Can you re read what you wrote and explain what you said.